# Changing reply header text in default mail app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, email

When I reply to mail in the default (non-gmail) mail application, the "RE:" text in the header, and the "xxx wrote" text before the quoted message are in Hebrew.

How Can I change them (I would like them to be the standard English texts, as not all of my recipients read Hebrew).

I have a Samsung Galaxy S, and it is rooted, if that helps.

Comment: was the original messages, including the subject in Hebrew? Is your default language on the device Hebrew?

Comment: The original message was not in Hebrew.
The default language on the device is.

Comment: changing the default language to none Hebrew should solve the problem. I know that may be a pain, but the only other option then is to manually change it. these areas of the email messages are "populated" and use the device language to get the values to use.

Comment: Changing the default language indeed solves this problem. Too bad I can't change just this part.

Do you want to write your comment as an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the default language to non Hebrew should solve the problem. I know that may be a pain, but the only other option then is to manually change it. these areas of the email messages are "populated" and use the device language to get the values to use.